# View Form Creation Code in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to view the form creation code in Access VBA? I don't mean the event listener code that is viewable in the VBE from View>Code in the form's Design View. I mean the code that is used to create the components, and add them to the form. I would like to programatically set Form properties; doing this from the Properties dialog is quite slow (and annoying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could get the form definition from the system table where it is stored (MSysObjects), but it isn't in a format that is practical to work against.

In theory you could avoid using the graphical designer to layout your form and create all the controls/set their properties dynamically in the form_load event. However, this wouldn't be much of a time-saver.

Assuming the gist of the question is whether there is an XML like declarative way to define a form layout similar to WPF. The answer is no.

Comment: Rather than XML-like way similar to WPF, because I know Access doesn't use XML, I was more thinking of a NetBeans-like approach where the code from the GUI builder is viewable & editable. But thanks, I ddidn't think to use the form_load event.

Comment: Yup. The declarative way is pretty much hidden under the covers, but there is nothing stopping you from using the netbeans approach, it is just more work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to create a form to design.
Vba include CreateControl Method (see [MSDN Office-11 Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221167%28v=office.11%29.aspx) )
And you can add to this controls any event procedure like OnClick, OnFocus, etc. (see [MSDN Office-11 Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221169%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
You can manipulate the width, height, etc.. properties as simple as me.control.width
I developed some time ago a form that could customized OnResize event to create different views depend of screen resolution and use all of this.

Answer (score 0):

All (?) the properties can be set through VBA for both the form and the controls.

```
Sub FormInDesignView()
Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control

Set frm = Screen.ActiveForm
frm.Caption = "New"

For Each ctl In frm.Controls

    ctl.Name = "txt" & ctl.Name
    ctl.ForeColor = vbRed

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the VBA code to create forms; I was wondering if the Form designer in Access allows the user to view/edit the code it creates. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not directly possible to do what you want. But if you insisted, you could use the undocumented Application.SaveAsText/LoadFromText commands and process the resulting text file.

Why you think this is a useful way to work in Access, I haven't a clue -- it's completely antithetical to the purpose and design of Access. Give up on your habits from other development tools and learn the Access way of doing things. You'll be a lot happier and productive in the long run.